# The "How to Ask" block on some meta sites contains a typo

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, page-rendering

The content of the "How to Ask" block contains a typo, in some meta sites; the following two screenshots show what appears in meta.drupal.stackexchange.com, and meta.cooking.stackexchange.com.

> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you''re discussing.

It should be *you're discussing*.

[image: meta.drupal.stackexchange.com]
  [image: meta.cooking.stackexchange.com]

Comment: I quickly checked the Q&A sites where I have an account, and it seems that every meta site on stackexchange.com (which excludes discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) have the same typo in the same block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default help had `''` in it and is now fixed.